# Spring Boot version 2.1.4 application terminates soon after it starts

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot application with version 2.1.4 Release. On running the Application, it terminates soon after it is started.

I have tried with version 2.0.3 Release, with this version i was able to run the application successfully.

The project structure was same for both the version , which i had tried.

I was using the 2.1.4 since , JDK 11 support is enabled on 2.1.x.

I am attaching my POM file here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what is printed on the console when it fails?

Comment: In Console there was no error printed. Normal log messages were there. I have fixed the issue adding the dependency <dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>''

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was with embedded netty server was not bind with application . I have this is only in case with Spring Boot version  2.1.4, since for me version 2.0.3 was working fine.

If you are using the version 2.1.4. Please add the below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```